# Copy single cell in Excel, paste into Word, save as PDF and repeat 1,000+ times

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I need to copy a URL from a single cell in Excel, paste it into a Word document, then save it as a PDF, and repeat for every row in that column. Manually it would take a good amount of time and I figured why not try to ask here.

Comment: http://www.excelvbatutor.com/vba_book/vbabook_ed2.pdf Here is a little tutorial for beginners. It will get you some basics.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run this, from the VBA browser within Excel, under the tools menu choose "References".

Then make sure both "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library" and "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library" are checked, and hit OK.

If 14.0 isn't there, check both boxes for whatever version you have showing up.

This code assume that (1) data starts in cell A1, and continues one cell at a time (A1, A2, A3, etc.) and (2) the output folder already exists.

```
Sub URLtoPDF()

  Dim DocPath As String
  Dim DocNumber As Integer
  Dim MsgBoxCompleted

  Range("A1").Select
  DocNumber = 1

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    Dim AppWord As Word.Application
    Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    AppWord.Visible = False

    ActiveCell.Copy

    DocPath = "C:\docs\url" & DocNumber & ".pdf"

    'Create and save pdf
    AppWord.Documents.Add
    AppWord.Selection.Paste
    AppWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=DocPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF

    'Prepare for next loop
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    AppWord.Quit (wdDoNotSaveChanges)
    Set AppWord = Nothing
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    DocNumber = DocNumber + 1

  Loop

  MsgBoxCompleted = MsgBox("Process complete.", vbOKOnly, "Process complete")

End Sub
```

The desired output location can be changed by changing the path portion of the DocPath variable assignment.

Good luck!

Comment: I'd like to add that the results in the PDF's will be wrapped to the width of the cell, so make sure you've resized the cell appropriately before hand.